# configuring cisco wireless access point via snmp

Tags: cisco, snmp, access-point

Is it possible to configure Cisco aironet access points via SNMP? For example for basic functionalities such as;

- setting SSID
- setting authentication method
- creating VLANs

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

you can indirectly configure any IOS Cisco device via SNMP. it involves sending/receiving the configuration file via TFTP, using SNMP to initiate the transfers.

see http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk648/tk362/technologies_configuration_example09186a0080094aa6.shtml